# Get the value of an <input type="text"> that was created dynamically inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

i would like to get the value of an `<input type="text">` that was created dynamically inside a modal and put it into variable "newcomment".
This is how i make the input:

```
    var newcomment;
    var p = $("<p>");
    p.append("Some text");
    p.append("</p>");
    p.append("<input type='text'id='comment_text' value='Comment'"+"onblur=newcomment=$('#comment_text').val()"+" onfocus=if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''>"+"</input>");
    $("div.modal-body").append(p);
```

The problem is when i write something like "ok" inside the textbox in the modal, and after i focusout from the textbox: newcomment seems not update to "ok" and still have the default "Comment" value.

Comment: Ignore last comment, your code is, well, kinda sloppy. You should put the logic into functions in a JS file and just run the function in the onfocus/onblur.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon 
I'm not sure that I understand what you mean.

Comment: Means he just downVoted your question

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I am referring to "You should put the logic into functions in a JS file and just run the function in the onfocus/onblur"

Comment: He means my first comment. And I dislike when people downvote without adding useful information. I'll provide an example of what I meant in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** You need to use `newcomment=this.value` instead of `newcomment=$('#comment_text').val()`
**2nd:** No need to add `+` signs in your input html code while you not trying to concatenate string by putting variables to it

```js
var newcomment;
    var p = $("<p>");
    p.append("Some text");
    p.append("</p>");
    p.append("<input type='text' id='comment_text'  value='Comment' onblur='newcomment=this.value; alert(newcomment);' onfocus=if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='' />");
    $("body").append(p);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer here, but might help you get at the root of the problem.

JS:

```
var newComment, defaultValue;

function doOnBlur(){
    newComment = $('#comment_text').val()
}

function doOnFocus(){
    if($('#comment_text').val() == defaultValue){
        $('#comment_text').val('')
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='comment_text' placeholder='Comment' onblur='doOnBlur()' onfocus='doOnFocus()' /> 
<!-- inputs dont have a close tag, also should use placeholder for temporary text -->
```

from here, you can set breakpoints in the debugger and see where your code is going wrong. You can also modify the functions much more easily rather than writing the executing code in the HTML